# Use Google Fonts In ffmpeg fontfile

Tags: ffmpeg

I am wanting to use Google Fonts in my ffmpeg video creations for text. Here is what I have and it's not working at all.

```
$font = "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica";

$cmd .= "drawtext=enable='between(t,".$fi.",".$li.")':fontfile=".$font.":fontsize=".$fontsize.":fontcolor=".$color.":x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h/2)+".$n.":text='".$arr[$j]."',";
```

Of course, this works with .ttf fonts but I really want to use Google Fonts.

I have also tried `$font = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica"` that does not work either.

I have a feeling that ffmpeg does not use woff2 fonts but I have seen a site that does this I just can't say 100% for sure that they use Google Fonts in the creation, but they do use them in the selection of the font which leads me to believe they use them in the creation of the video.

Comment: How is that a PHP question? I am guessing you pass `$cmd` to ffmpeg somewhere?

Comment: I don't know why that switched to php. It had ffmpeg in the tags.

Comment: Have you tried storing the font locally instead of passing an URL?

Comment: @ArSeN yes, that's what I ended up doing and it's working. I did not know if I needed to delete this question or leave it and just click the Answer Your Question so others see it.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, ffmpeg can not handle a font that is passed by URL but rather expects a locally reachable file with the font.

Comment: Font rendering in drawtext is handled by an external lib freetype, which calls fopen to open the font file.

Comment: @Gyan and does fopen support resources being loaded by URL?